# No overloaded version with these arguments - var param with read/write property

Tags: delphi, parameters, overloading, delphi-10.3-rio

I have two overloaded procedures, of which I want to call the second one:

```
function  ModifySyncProperties(AEWSItemId: String; AEvent: TcxSchedulerEvent; var AEWSChangeKey: String): Boolean; overload;
function  ModifySyncProperties(AEWSItemId: String; ATTID: Integer; ASyncID: String; var AEWSChangeKey: String): Boolean; overload;
```

This fails with an error, though:

```
lSuccess := FDMExchange.ModifySyncProperties(lEWSId, lApp.EventID, lNewOutlookID, lApp.EWSItemChangeKey);
```

> There is no overloaded version of 'ModifySyncProperties' that can be called with these arguments

This works, though:

```
lChangeKey := lApp.EWSItemChangeKey;
lSuccess := FDMExchange.ModifySyncProperties(lEWSId, lApp.EventID, lNewOutlookID, lChangeKey);
lApp.EWSItemChangeKey := lChangeKey;
```

Here are the types and variables:

```
lNewOutlookID,
lEWSID,
lChangeKey     : String;
lApp           : TEWSAppointment;
lSuccess       : Boolean;
```

`TEWSAppointment` is defined in the `interface` section of another unit as this:

```
TEWSAppointment = class
private
  FEventID: Integer;
  ...
  FEWSItemChangeKey: String;
  ...
public
  property EventID: Integer read FEventID write FEventID;
  ...
  property EWSItemChangeKey: String read FEWSItemChangeKey write FEWSItemChangeKey;
  ...
end;
```

Why does the compiler not accept the read/write `lApp` property as a `var` parameter?

I'm using Delphi Rio 10.3.1.

Comment: Var parameters in Delphi are passed by reference. Property of an object might not have one, because its value can as well be computed by a method. Delphi doesn't differentiate between properties backed by a field or method and doesn't allow properties to be accepted as var parameters [which is documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Properties_(Delphi)): *Unlike fields, properties cannot be passed as var parameters, nor can the @ operator be applied to a property*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [`var` parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters) says:

> If a routine's declaration specifies a var parameter, you must pass an assignable expression - that is, a variable, typed constant (in the {$J+} state), dereferenced pointer, field, or indexed variable to the routine when you call it.

A property does not meet this requirement.

Further, the documentation for [properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#About_Properties) calls this out explicitly:

> Unlike fields, properties cannot be passed as var parameters, nor can the @ operator be applied to a property.

---

At the implementation level, the ABI, `var` parameters are implemented by passed the address of the variable. Since a property does not necessarily have a backing variable with an address, the compiler cannot directly obtain such a variable address.

Furthermore, if the property getter or setter perform actions beyond reading or writing to a variable, then they would need to be called.

In principle at least the language could support the usage you wish by declaring a local variable and compiling this code:

```
localVar := myProperty;
foo(localVar); 
myProperty := localVar;
```

However, the designers of the compiler did not implement this when properties were introduced to the language.

Comment: Personally I would avoid such a feature, because it could be confusing. The caller might think that the value is assigned to property deep inside the routine, while in fact it would be assigned after the routine has returned. Ref properties didn't make their way into C# either; not even in form of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @PeterWolf I agree